# Firebase console - problem receiving test push FCM notification in android device

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I am sending push notification using firebase console and i am getting "0% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: 0". and push notification is not displaying in mobile..If anyone got same experience and solve issue then please suggest me how can i solve this issue. I followed all the thing..that i added json file that i got from firebase.

Comment: Thanks...after long time research i solved it..now its closed. I just replace tools:node="replace" to  tools:node="merge" in manifest file.

Comment: How you solve this issue? I am getting the same. "0% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: 0" for different flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the following:

- Have you configured your android package name correctly.
- Did you place the google-services.json file in android/src folder.
- Make sure you have done all steps present in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) (If you using android studio i suggest going with option 2)
- Get user token to send firebase message [Follow the steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

After all these if you still can't receive push notifications try setting channelid in advanced messaging options

Comment: yes i followed all the steps but not getting notification

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client link step by step and you will be good to go for your push notification using fcm and if you already implemented the basic things then compare your code with the sample code step by step mentions on the link. you must find out the error. let me know if it resolves your issue.

Comment: i followed all the steps..and i got "100% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: 1"..but when i push from cloud messaging..still not getting notification..

Comment: you are using the FCM token to send the push notification from firebase console right ?

Comment: Yes,FCM token id but not getting notification

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build --> clean project -->Rebuild project

(Build is at top in android studio)

Why it was not working - You must have had deleted google-services.json file and re-added it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have only one firebase project configured for this app (if no then delete one you dont plan to use)
2. Go to firebase setiings -> Left top angle -> settings icon -> Project settings ->
   scroll to bottom, then make sure to add `SHA certificate fingerprints  Type`. [How to get it](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)
3. Then (still on this page) press `See SDK instructions` button. And place `google-services.json` file in your project.
4. If all this steps passed for you and you still getting this error then just wait a little bit, for me it take 2 days, before it started working.